# JPanel not being aligned

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have 3 JPanels that are in a vertical boxlayout panel inside the WEST of a borderlayout jpanel. the first 2 jpanels are aligned to the left but the last one is not. I am unsure as to why I have tried using the alignment method but it seems to do nothing.

CODE:

```
public void create(){
    JPanel body = new JPanel();
    BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
    body.setLayout(border);
    
    JPanel LEFT = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout LV = new BoxLayout(LEFT, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    LEFT.setLayout(LV);
    
    JLabel header = new JLabel("PizzaBoy Brewing");
    header.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40));
    header.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    
    JButton Calculate = new JButton("CALCULATE");
    
    JPanel numIngredPanel = numIngredPanel();
    JPanel batchSize = batchSize();
    JPanel modList = modList();
    JPanel ingredList = ingredList();
    JPanel batchInfo = batchInfo();
    
    
    LEFT.add(numIngredPanel);
    LEFT.add(batchSize);
    LEFT.add(modList);
    
    body.add(header, border.NORTH);
    body.add(LEFT, border.WEST);
    body.add(Calculate, border.SOUTH);
    body.add(ingredList, border.CENTER);
    body.add(batchInfo,border.EAST);
    
    //numIngredPanel.setAlignmentX(5);
    //batchSize.setAlignmentX(5);
    //modList.setAlignmentX(5);
    
    this.add(body);
    pack();
    revalidate();
}
```

CODE FOR LIST MODIFIER JPANEL:

```
public JPanel modList(){
    JPanel body = new JPanel();
    
    BoxLayout box = new BoxLayout(body, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    body.setLayout(box);
    
    JLabel header = new JLabel();
    JLabel note = new JLabel();
    
    header.setText("List Modifier");
    note.setText("Note*: removes last field on list.");
    
    LineBorder border = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK); 
    Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);
    body.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(border,margin));
    
    JButton add = new JButton();
    JButton del = new JButton();
    
    add.setText("Add Ingredient");
    del.setText("Remove Ingredient");
    
    body.add(header);
    body.add(add);
    body.add(del);
    body.add(note);
    //me.add(body);
    pack();
    revalidate();
    return body;
}
```

Current Display:
[image]

Comment: The `setAlignmentX(...)` method should work. It needs to be applied to all 3 panels. And of course you should be using 0.0f for all 3 panels, not 0.5f. If it still doesn't work then post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is simply create a frame with a panel containing 3 panels each with a different preferred size and background color. Then add this panel to the LINE_START of the BorderLayout. Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character or be fully capitalized. Learn and follow Java naming conventions.